# INSERT INTO ...SELECT syntax error in join operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to write a shopping basket into a order + orderline in a sql database from C# asp.net. 
the orderline will contain a ordernumber, total price, productid, quantity etc. for every item in the basket. The order itself will contain the ordernumber as primary key and will be linked to the different lines through it.
Everything worked fine yesterday, but now as i tried to use a SELECT command in the insert into statement to get things more dynamic i'm getting the above described syntax error.

Does anybody know what's wrong with this statement:

```
INSERT INTO [order] 
        (klant_id,totaalprijs,btw,subtotaal,verzendkosten)
SELECT  klant.id
,       SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs)
,       SUM(orderregel.btw)
,       SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs) - SUM(orderregel.btw)
,       7.50 
FROM    orderregel
INNER JOIN  
        klant 
ON      [order].klant_id = klant.id  
WHERE   klant.username = 'jerry' 
GROUP BY 
        id;
```

the ordernumber in the "order" table is on autonumber, in the asp codebehind there is a for each which handles the lines being written for every product, there's an index set on 0 outside of this loop and is heightened with 1 every end of it. The executenonquery of the order is only executed once at the beginning of the first loop and the lines are added after with MAX(ordernumber) as ordernumber.

I hope i have provided enough information and somebody is capable of helping me.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
thanks everybody, using this query did it!

> INSERT INTO [order] 
>           (klant_id,totaalprijs,btw,subtotaal,verzendkosten) SELECT (SELECT klant.id FROM klant WHERE klant.username = 'jerry') ,
>   SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs) ,       SUM(orderregel.btw) ,
>   SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs) - SUM(orderregel.btw) ,       7.50  FROM
>   orderregel;

Comment: Your EDIT query won't work.  Try to insert two orders.  Then check if the totaalprijs for your second order is correct.

Comment: Hmmm yeah i noticed it, do you see a fix here? I tried doing it alone now but being bussy at work all day and programming after getting home isn't too good for my tought process ;)

Comment: You'd have to figure out how to insert the relation between order and orderline.  There's a possible solution in my answer.  I'd sleep a night on it :)

Comment: Allright, thanks man, maybe that's for the best anyways. I haven't been programming for long now but it didn't take me long to figure out breaks every now and then really gives you new ideas and views on things!

Answer (score 3):

You have used `[order]` in a JOIN, when it should be `orderregel` I guess.

```
FROM    orderregel
    INNER JOIN klant ON [order].klant_id = klant.id
```

should be:

```
FROM    orderregel
    INNER JOIN klant ON orderregel.klant_id = klant.id
```

**Edit:**

Why not just using:

```
INSERT INTO [order] 
        (klant_id,totaalprijs,btw,subtotaal,verzendkosten)
SELECT  (SELECT klant.id FROM klant WHERE klant.username = 'jerry')
,       SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs)
,...
```

... and avoid JOIN with klant table?

Comment: Also, theres `GROUP BY id` , without mentioning the table, this may also lead to an error (if there are multiple tables with column "id" in use)

Comment: "klant" means customer in Dutch; it's unlikely that an order line will have a relation to a customer.

Comment: Thats why i started the comment with "also", cause (a) maybe he will see this after fixing the first error and (b) cause it's worth mentioning when dealing with joins aggregation ;)

Comment: @Andomar - makes sense, but it wasn't clear from the question - for non-dutch speakers :)

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, the thing is that orderregel doesn't have a klant.id, it is the customer id which is read when writing the order to decide which customer to write the order to. I've tried using a second inner join in the statement joining order inside the select but for that i had to do it ON order.ordernummer = orderregel.ordernummer which isn't created yet at this point in the code behind.

Comment: user1477356 - Unfortunately, as @Andomar mentioned, there isn't much sense in your query. You can't just doing insert to the table and expect to read the value from that table in JOIN. Maybe you could edit your question and explain a bit more on relation between Order and Klant classes.

Comment: After your edit, you're doing a `sum` on every order line in the system ;)

Comment: Hehe, yes... didn't see that there's no other WHERE in the query :) This really looks more difficult than it should be :) I think the question needs to be modified to have at least the schema for all tables involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to the table being inserted into.  After all, those rows aren't yet there before the insert completes!

Reading your query, it's clear that you're trying to insert the `klant` called `Jerry`.  But how do you specify which orderlines are used for the insert?

A possible solution:

1. Write the order first, with the klant id
2. Create the order lines.  You know the orderid from the first query (f.e. using `select SCOPE_IDENTITY()`
3. Update the order with totals

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, you're absolutely right here. I'm reading the username of the customer from the C# codebehind user.authenticated built in feature. is there any way to INNER JOIN klant ON klant.username = 'jerry' 
I'll just move the parameter in the codebehind then...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
INSERT INTO [order] 
        (klant_id,totaalprijs,btw,subtotaal,verzendkosten)
SELECT  klant.id
,       SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs)
,       SUM(orderregel.btw)
,       SUM(orderregel.totaalprijs) - SUM(orderregel.btw)
,       7.50 
FROM    orderregel
INNER JOIN   klant ON orderregel.id = klant.id
INNER JOIN   [order] ON [order].klant_id = klant.id
WHERE   klant.username = 'jerry' 
GROUP BY id;